# My RCP Client is not returning a deep copy of an object

Tags: json, dart, rpc

I have been working on an RCP Client to handle weather data.

What i do is 2 things, first i scraped the JSON i will be using and put it into a dart file.  See: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a9c1fe8ce34c608eaa28

My server.dart page, will import the weather data, and then carry out the following:

```
import "dart:io";
import "weather_data.dart";
import "dart:convert";
import "package:rpc/rpc.dart";

find ApiServer _apiServer = new ApiServer(prettyPrint:true);
main() async {
  Weather w = new Weather(WeatherJson);
  TestServer ts = new TestServer(w);
  _apiServer.addApi(ts);
  HttpServer server = await HttperServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 12345);
  server.listen(_apiServer.httpRequestHandler);
}

class Weather{
  Map weather;
  Weather(this.weather){
    Map get daily => weather["daily"];
  }
}

@ApiClass(name:"test_server", version: 'v1', description: 'This is a test server api to ping for some quick sample data.')
class TestServer {
  Weather myWeather;
  TestServer(this.myWeather){

  }

  @ApiMethod(method:'GET', path: 'daily')
  Map<String, Object> getDaily(){
    return myWeather.daily;
  }
}
```

So, the server starts correctly, and i will go to `localhost:12345/test_server/v1/daily` and it will return this:

```
{
 "summary": {},
 "icon": {},
 "data": {}
}
```

which is not correct.   If you look up the JSON data, summary and icon are both strings and data is an array.  They are also empty, and should contain the data i wanted to return.

Why does this occur?  Is it because i am returning a `Map<String, Object>`?  I was trying to set it up to be: `Map<String, dynamic>` but the dart compiler didnt like it.

How do i get this data to return the correct dataset?

The Dart website for RPC is located at: https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc
and you can see that under methods, the return value of a method can be either an instance of a class or a future.  That makes sense as per usual, so I set it to be a `Map<String,Object>` though trying to be vague about it by saying: `Map` was not sufficient.

**Edit:**

When doing this mostly in dart pad without RPC, it seems to work correctly, by a sample of: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3f6dc5779617ed427b75

This leads me to believe something is wrong with the Parsing tool as it seems the return type in dartpad allows to return `Map`, `Map<String, Object>`, and `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Would like a reason for the downvote.  I believe this is a well thought out question with a solid code example.

Comment: Don't worry too much. If someone downvotes without leaving a comment what needs to be improved, it's best to ignore it. I haven't used RPC therefore don't know what the problem is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having had a quick look at the RPC package README here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rpc, it seems that methods marked as Api methods (with @ApiMethod) should return an instance of a class with simple fields such as:

```
class ResourceMessage {
  int id;
  String name;
  int capacity;
}
```

The RPC package will take that instance and serialize it into JSON based on the field names.

From the README:

> The MyResponse class must be a non-abstract class with an unnamed
>   constructor taking no required parameters. The RPC backend will
>   automatically serialize all public fields of the the MyResponse
>   instance into JSON ...

You are returning a nested `Map` *representation* of the JSON you want the RPC operation to emit and would guess that the RPC package does not handle it as you are expecting it to.

Re: this from your question:

> This leads me to believe something is wrong with the Parsing tool as
>   it seems the return type in dartpad allows to return Map, Map, and Map.

There is no 'parsing' on JSON going on on your example. The data you have is a set of nested literal Dart `Map`s, `List`s and `String`s with the same structure as the JSON it was derived from. It just happens to look like JSON.

In your example you are just selecting and printing a sub-map of your data map (`data['daily']`), which prints out the `String` that results from calling `toString()` - which is recursive so you get the contents of all the nested maps and lists within it.

So it's not a 'deep copy' issue, but a difference in how `toString()` and the RPC code processes a set of nested maps.

BTW: the return type of your `getDaily()` method is immaterial. What is returned is just a `Map` whatever the declared return type of the method is. Remember types in Dart are optional and there for editors and compilers to spot potentially incorrect code. See https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#variables.

Comment: How would I go about resolving this then?  Stringify the result then parse it on the client?  That is a valid answer, but plausibly not the best.  Your answer is very informative, though I did see this on the *RPC Github* `Only the public fields of the classes are encoded/decoded. Currently supported types for the public fields are int, double, bool, String, DateTime, List, Map, and another message class.`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to piggyback off of @Argenti Apparatus here as there was a lot of information gained from him.

Long story short, the required return type of the method:

```
@ApiMethod(method:'GET', path: 'daily')
Map<String,Object> getDaily(){       // <-- Map<String,Object>
  return myWeather.daily;
}
```

is the error.

I went through and updated the method signature to be `Map<String,String>` and it parsed it entirely correct.  It did not parse the object as a string, but actually parsed it as a full recursed object.

I went through and for the sake of code cleanliness also changed signatures of Weather properties to reflect what they actually were, `Map<String,Object>` as well.

All in all, When defining it to be an value type of Object, it was returning curly braces, but setting it as a String parsed it correctly.

I ran it through JSLint to confirm it is correct as well.

I gave a +1 to the helper, I had to dig deeper into the code to see *WHY* it wasnt doing a Map correctly.

This also I feel, is plausibly a bug in RPC Dart.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm not sure this is a bug in the RPS package per se, but perhaps a a lack of documentation on how it deals with maps. BTW you might consider using Map<String, dynamic> as the type for heterogeneous maps.

Comment: I beat you to it, I tried `Map<String, dynamic>` and the Dart compiler was throwing a hissyfit over dynamic being used.

Comment: Compiler? This is server side code, right? What is actually complaining about that? BTW, can you accept my answer as answering your question if you feel it does - thx.

Comment: Server side code, but when it ran, it would parse it and didnt like the return signature.  Your answer is correct to some extent, but didnt explicitly figure out the error.  I wasnt sure if i should give you the points or me, as long as  users understood both posts.